# escaping tool for sed

Tags: regex, sed

My daily life is hard, i have to patch zillions of files manually, and it's like 80% of a time I'm writing sed regexps for patching files.

so for example I have a line of code:

```
"    Limit("POST", "*", ".*", 1000, PER_MINUTE),"
```

which I have inject into some file, in some specific place, so I'm using sed for this:

```
limits_py=/my/path/limits.py
sed -i "s/\ \ \ \ Limit(\"POST\",\ \"\*\",\ \"\.\*\",\ 10,\ PER_MINUTE),/\ \ \ \ Limit(\"POST\",\ \"\*\",\ \"\.\*\",\ 1000,\ PER_MINUTE),/" ${limits_py}
```

I'm really tired of writing sed regexps manually for every code string.

So question: how can I generate sed from string?

For example something like this would be a bliss:

```
echo 'someclass.somemethod("some_argument") # blah blah my comment here' > sed_generator --replace
```

it's really annoying to "adapt" every line for sed.. is there any tool for this? or even better `diff`'ing two files and generate sed regexp replacement for each diff? Maybe it's possible to sed without regexp?

Comment: am I the only one don't get what were you talking about?

Comment: edited a question. feel free to ask words you don't understand.

Comment: You already know sed. Use sed to generate the sed for you :-) If you are tired of the quoting issues, turn to more powerful language like Perl.

Comment: Why are you escaping the spaces?

Comment: because when you escaping code it's hard to say how many spaces out there, but even when i was coding php we always escaped spaces..

Comment: The sed commands are in quotes so plain spaces should be fine. (You may also be able to use \s - any whitespace character - if you want to be explicit.) As far as what you want to do it may be easier in another language (I once used Perl regexes to translate COBOL data descriptions into regexes that could parse the corresponding data record fields.)

Comment: So... what you want is a `sed` command that will put a backslash before every special character (e.g. '"'), is that right?

Comment: @Beta yes that's right, this may seem laziness but when you have  multiple lines text with zillions special chars everywhere, sed becomes a maddness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, try:

```
s|\(["*]\)|\\\1|g
```

(Notice the list of special characters in the brackets, currently just `"` and `*`.)

This will turn

```
"    Limit("POST", "*", ".*", 1000, PER_MINUTE),"
```

into

```
\"    Limit(\"POST\", \"\*\", \".\*\", 1000, PER_MINUTE),\"
```

Run this on the "before" line and the "after" line, paste the results together with `s|...|...|`, and you get:

```
s|\"    Limit(\"POST\", \"\*\", \".\*\", 1000, PER_MINUTE),\"|\"    Limit(\"POST\", \"\*\", \".\*\", 10, PER_MINUTE),\"|
```

which turns one into the other. Once you get this working (you may need more special characters, like `&` and `$`), we can work on improvements, like reading the "before" and "after" lines from files. (I'm not sure why you'd want to diff two files and do this for every difference-- why not just overwrite one file with the other?)